# Accounts and password management software

Tags: ftp, accounts

Is there any good/robust software for managing accounts. I work in web developement team, and what I need, is a software to manage accounts like:

- Web applications Accounts
- FTP Accounts
- Databases names, users and passwords ...
- SSH Accounts .. and related  notes
- Ability to share those informations with my coworkers and clients (So there must be some sort of roles or privileges mechanism)
- Of course, it has to be secure. (Encryption, backup, export)

By the way, I did a search before I ask this question, all that I can find is software for handling purely passwords (KeePass, LastPass, PassPack and others).
I can go without 'form fill' or 'auto login' functions.

Comment: This question seems too broad. And I assume that you're looking for libraries? The term software is too generic to say what you're really looking for.

Answer (score 1):

We use KeePass at my company to track those things.  All of the IT staff have the master password (we're not big enough to have sub-groups of accounts each person needs to see), and it works ok.  Backups are taken care of outside the app by the same backup software that keeps track of everything else.

Answer (score 0):

It may be overkill or more complicated than what you're looking for, but [CPanel](http://www.cpanel.net/) is frequently used by webhosting companies as a central tool for managing users, ftp accounts, ssh, databases, etc. It's highly configurable, but also takes effort to set up. It is also rather pricey, so your team's financial backing may determine whether it's a practical solution.

It would be nice if you could elaborate on what you mean by software for "managing" these things. Do you just want to be able to keep track of them as records, or do you want to actively be able to configure all of those services from one interface? Recordkeeping might be easiest to do with your own homebrewed database and accompanying interface, but for other stuff, you'll need something more complex.

Comment: What I meant by 'managing', is mainly keeping records in  a safe place, and be able to search them, and share them ... The first tought was to build our own system, but I was  cursious to see how others are doing this, and not to mention the fact that we don't want to reinvent the wheel, if there's some product out there that meets our needs. By the way, I came across, this product "www.cpassman.org" ... haven't try it yet!